# Deleting array without calling destructors

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management, c++11, destructor

I am working on an application with high performance and memory needs. With that I mean 80 cores and 500 GB of RAM. To save some memory, I use my own dynamic array (16 B overhead) as opposed to `std::vector` (24 B overhead), which matters if you have billions of them.
My question relates to expanding that array which looks like this:

```
//private
template <class ArrType>
void DynamicArray<ArrType>::reallocate(unsigned newCapacity) {
    if (newCapacity < _size) return;
    if (capacity == newCapacity) return;

    ArrType * newArray = new ArrType[newCapacity];
    capacity = newCapacity;

    //for (unsigned i = 0; i < _size; i++) {
    //    newArray[i] = array[i];
    //}

    memcpy(newArray, array, _size * sizeof(ArrType));

    if(array) delete [] array;
    array = newArray;
}
```

As you can see, pretty standard reallocation, but I tested `memcpy` and it was about 10 times faster than using a `for` cycle. The problem is when I call `delete`, it will call destructors for objects of `ArrType`, which is a problem when `ArrType` has its own dynamic allocations. The copy in `newArray` will use deleted memory. Is there any way to delete the old array without calling destructors?

Comment: Waaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiit. You're caring about 8 goddamn bytes of `vector` footprint, but don't care about the footprint of all those billions of dynamic allocations?

Comment: @crashmstr: If you're going to be pedantic, it's a `for` *statement*. Otherwise, "loop" and "cycle" are both perfectly cromulent colloquialisms.

Comment: if `~ArrType` does *nothing*, with optimization, `delete []` will *just* delete the pointer, else `~ArrType` has to be called or you will have memory leaks.

Comment: @crashmstr: Don't force your colloquial terminology on other people. The only thing it definitely is is a `for` statement.

Comment: Note that in your solution, you construct 'empty' `ArrType`, you should look at `placement new`.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Yes the idea is to make room for these allocations. There are 4294967296 (as you expect 2^32) of these arrays that create large hash table. Realocation of one array will double the size of that array as in vector, but when the table is full all the arrays will shring_to_fit() to make room for next phases of algoritm (this is 2 out of 4) which takes also a lot of memory. It's 103GB vs 69GB for empty table. Full table will take about 300GB (with my arrays). The table is created using std::vector and is done in this way to use index as a hash - makes a lot of memory savings.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Yet everyone understood that. That for statement creates a loop or cycle. From mathematical point of view there is no statement but only loop.

Comment: @TjSnake: indeed, "cycle" is a fine word, as I said. I was responding to a (now deleted) comment claiming you should have said "loop" instead.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Oh I see. Didn't catch that deleted one. Sorry.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace your `memcpy` with:

```
std::move(array, array + _size, newArray);
```

And require that the type `ArrType` must have a correct move or copy assignment operator.

But in real life, just use `vector<ArrType>`.

In fact `vector` is better than this: rather than allocating an array (which runs a constructor if the type has one) and then move-assigning (which over-writes what `new` just did) it allocates raw memory and then uses the move constructor with placement new.

So, if you absolutely positively need a version of `vector` that uses a smaller type for `size_type` than the one in your implementation I suppose the thing to do is to re-implement `vector` under a new name with that change. You can use the source in your implementation to help you: that way you will have solutions in front of you to this problem and all the other problems involved.

Comment: Yes that's what I am doint - reimplementing vector so it would be interchangable if need be. I have tested speed of move function as opose to for cycle on array of size 1000000. It does the job in about 2000 clocks. The cycle took 11000. So it does do the desired trick. Thanks.